# Counterexample to show that a formula is not logically valid?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic

How to find a counterexample to show that the wfs is not logically valid ?

This is the formula $$[\forall x\forall y(A(x,y)\to A(y,x))\land\forall x\forall y\forall z(A(x,y)\land A(y,z)\to A(x,z))]\to\forall x A(x,x)$$

I tried to construct the interpretation as this:

Domain=$\mathbb N, A(x,y)=x<y$ and with this I get this $\forall x A(x,x)$ false but $[\forall x\forall y(A(x,y)\to A(y,x))\land\forall x\forall y\forall z(A(x,y)\land A(y,z)\to A(x,z))]$ is false too, and it should be true.

How can I find such interpretation? Is there a trick on how to find it?

When we talk about just one variable like this $A(x)$ the common counterexamples are like $A(x)= "x $ is even", but I don't know what to do when it's whit 2 variables like this $A(x,y)$.

Comment: Maybe something really simple works? What if $A(x,y)$ is the empty relation, i.e., it's **never** true. Then $\forall xA(x,x)$ is surely false. What happens to the stuff on the left of the $\to$?

Comment: @bof it's true, so it works. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula claims that:

> If a relation $A$ is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) and [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), then it must be [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation).

The three properties of being reflexive, symmetric, and transitive are well-known to be fully independent, and it's possible to construct relations that have any subset of the three.

For our counterexample, take the domain to be $\mathbb N$, and define $A(x, y) \equiv$ "$x$ and $y$ are both even". Then $A$ is symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive (e.g.: $A(1, 1)$ is false).

Comment: how did you come up with the idea "x and y are both even "?

Comment: I have another formulas and I am trying to find the counterexample, I tried with "x and y are both even", "x=y", "x>y", and I just can't find the right interpretation.

Comment: @Michelle A relation that is symmetric and transitive but not (necessarily) reflexive is known as a [partial equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_equivalence_relation). One way of creating counter-examples is to take any equivalence relation and simply add elements to the carrier set (which aren't related to anything). In fact, this is the *only* way of creating counter-examples. (Why?)

Comment: The _empty relation_ on a nonempty set may be an even simpler example.

Comment: @DerekElkins What do you mean with add elements to the carrier set?  Can you give an example? .The way you say to create counter-examples works for any formula (even a formula that doesn't a have relations)?

Comment: @Michelle I'm only talking about this particular example, where, as Adriano states (in different words), the formula can be interpreted as (falsely) claiming all partial equivalence relations are equivalence relations. The idea is simply to let $\approx$ be an equivalence relation on a set $X$, i.e. ${\approx}\subseteq X\times X$, and then you have a partial equivalence relation on any $Y\supseteq X$ defined as $\forall y_1,y_2.y_1\sim y_2 \iff y_1\in X\land y_2\in X\land y_1\approx y_2$. If $Y\neq X$ then this will be a counter-example, and all counter-examples are of this form.

Comment: @DerekElkins I don't understand what you wrote :/, but it sounds really interesting that all counter-examples are of that form.